# How is debugger variable content displayed implemented

Tags: debugging

I was wondering how to implement the debuggger mouse over display functionality, U know when u have set a breakpoint in a degugger, say in VS and you hover over a variable and the context is displayed.

I'm curious as to how that would be implemented?

Bob.

Comment: What part of it are you wondering about?

Comment: Curious to how it was implemented, more than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are debugging visualizers and here is a link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx) for writing custom visualizer